# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app get Volume Serial Number and FileID

Tags: silverlight, winapi, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I tried to use [GetFileInformationByHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953(v=vs.85).aspx) with [FILE_ID_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802691(v=vs.85).aspx) struct, but it is not working when app is installed on SD card (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

FILE_ID_INFO is said to be supported only on desktop apps, so it is strange that it is working when app is installed on device memory, is there another way to get this info?
Thanks!

Comment: My documentation for [FILE_ID_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802691.aspx) claims, that it is supported for **server** OSs only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just impossible with current API.